vue js Cannot find module './undefined'
I'm using Vuejs, and calling my symfony API with a get route.
I have the result, an array of objects, but I still have this error:

Cannot find module './undefined'

When I try with an array with only one object, without the API call, there is no problem.
beforeMount() {
    axios.get('/products')
    .then((response) => {
      this.cards = [response.data['hydra:member'][0]]
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    })
    .finally(() => {

    })
}


I think you should use onMounted API in this case to fetch api when the page load

I recommend using created or mounted indeed and also use async/await rather than .then. Try to debug the whole thing step by step too, rather than having [response.data['hydra:member'][0]].

When i add display the result from the API in console, i have the expected result.
But the application doesn't show it int the interface, and i have this error.

Please follow the rest of my previous comment then.
